# NativeQuery return with Spring Boot and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I using NativeQuery with Spring Boot and Hibernate, but my NativeQuery returns one `List<Object[]>`, is it possible to map to my object? instead of returning

```
List<Object[]>
```

I want to return

```
List<MyObj>
```

Comment: try to use in your select something like "SELECT new com.yourpackage.MyObj(e.attr1, e.attr2) from MyEntity e WHERE ..."  edit: this probably wont work with nativeQuery...I've overlooked that.

Comment: please share your select. It would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Spring Data Repositories a `@Query` method with the `nativeQuery = true` can return a List.

Example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 20 CUSTOMER.ID, CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME"
            + " FROM CUSTOMER"
            + " ORDER BY CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Customer> findRecentCustomers();
```

Comment: But I not return the defaul entity, I need to returno another object. tks

Comment: You can return another object, as long as the return fields match the fields contained within the object.  If you're still having trouble, please share a small example on GitHub that illustrates the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: here have my method with @Query: https://gist.github.com/fabioebner/ed0981b8b7c1b27cd14df399c44eee4b  I put my return, so I want to return my Object and not one List<Object[]> tks

Comment: You first need to create MyObj with a top level annotation of @Table(name = "table_name")  Then add a field for each selection you are making.  Example: private Date data;  Then for each field, annotate it with the column name @Column(name = "column_name")  Finally use List<MyObj> as the return type of your nativeQuery and that should be it, assuming you've chosen the appropritate data types in MyObj.  If you're still stuck, a full example, with dummy data, would be useful.